# Notation for sum over element wise multiplication

Tags: matrices, hadamard-product

Im looking for  a  typical notation  for  the  sum  over the elements after an element-wise  multiplication  of two matrices $A$, $B$ (hadamard  product).

Is  it  correct  to  write $\sum  A \odot B$ without  further  specifiying  what $\sum$ is doing  or  do  i  need  to  use  row  and column  indices?
Thanks!

Comment: If $A = (a_{ij})$ and $B = (b_{ij})$, did you mean the sum $\sum_{i,j} a_{ij}b_{ij}$?

Comment: Yes. Thats  how i would do  it with  row  and  col  indices.  So $\sum  A\odot B$ where $\odot $ is the  hadamard  product,  is not  valid?

Comment: That is little understandable (unless you specify it). Why not $\operatorname{trace}(AB^\textsf{T})?$

Comment: That would imply  unnecessary  Matrix multiplication

Answer (score 7):

$
\def\o{{\large\tt1}}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
$The Frobenius product (aka the double-dot product) is what you want
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij}
 &\;=\; \trace{A^TB}  \;=\; \trace{AB^T} \\
A:A &= \big\|A\big\|^2_F
 &\;=\; \trace{A^TA}  \;=\; \trace{AA^T} \\
\\
}$$
Note that the Hadamard and Frobenius products commute
$$\eqalign{
(A\odot B):C
 &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij}C_{ij} \\
 &= A:(B\odot C) \\
}$$
and that the *all-ones* matrix $\o$ is the identity for the Hadamard product
$$\o\odot A=A$$
Therefore one can sum over the elements of a Hadamard product
$$\eqalign{
\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n \;\o_{ij}\,\LR{A\odot B}_{ij} 
&= \o:(A\odot B) \\
&= (\o\odot A):B \\
&= A:B \\
}$$
which was your original intent.

Comment: A stupid question: In Aᵀ B we only need to assure that Aᵀ columns number is the same as B rows number. But the sum of Aᵢⱼ Bᵢⱼ the matrix A and B need to be the exact same size right ?

Comment: To be honest I prefer the notation from wikipedia: $\langle A, B\rangle_F$ for the Frobenius dot product. The double dots look reminicent of division for me, so I have to fight against the intuition that it is assymetric.

Comment: Yes, but $A:B$ takes 3 keystrokes while $\langle A, B\rangle_F$ takes 22.